# C# open PPTX file to a specific slide index

Tags: c#

I am looking at opening a powerpoint file, .pptx, to a specific slide index. For this example, lets say slide 3.

I have code that opens the file, but I can not get it to open to Slide 3 on its own.

Code to open pptx file:

```
string file_path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test_Folder\myppt.pptx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState ofalse = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState otrue = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
pptApp.Visible = otrue;
pptApp.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations ps = pptApp.Presentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation p = ps.Open(file_path, ofalse, ofalse, otrue);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(p.Windows.Count.ToString());
```

I've done some reading, and my thoughts to solve this include adding a place where `p.Slides[2]` comes in to send it to slide index of 3 ( Thinking it goes 0, 1 ,2 like an array, I could be wrong here) . I just can not figure out where to put this in my code block, or if there is a different way, I have not seen that.

Comment: You should be able to just do this: `p.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide(3, MsoTriState.msoFalse);`

Comment: @Icemanind I added that line after the `p = ps.open` line, and i got had an issue with the run, 'Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  There is currently no slide show view for this presentation.'

Comment: Run the slideshow first using this: `p.SlideShowSettings.Run()`. Then after that, add the line I posted up above.

Comment: Success! Thank you! @Icemanind

Answer (score 0):

As per Icemanind in the comments, adding in two lines after the `p.Open` line in the above code, the power point opened up to the correct slide.

Those two lines being:

```
p.SlideShowSettings.Run()
p.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide(3, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

Functional Code:

```
string file_path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test_Folder\myppt.pptx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState ofalse = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState otrue = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
pptApp.Visible = otrue;
pptApp.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations ps = pptApp.Presentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation p = ps.Open(file_path, ofalse, ofalse, otrue);
p.SlideShowSettings.Run()
p.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide(3, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(p.Windows.Count.ToString());
```